# Javascript function .filter() not working on Iphone?

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, iphone

I am working in Angular 11 and facing an issue that when I try to filter the array using search filter pipe (custom pipe) then it won't work on iPhone.

// customSearch pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
@Pipe({
  name: "customSearch"
})
export class CustomSearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  /** Function to filter the data **/
  transform(items: any[], filter: Object): any {
    if (!items || !filter) {
      return items;
    }
    return items.filter(
      item => item.location.location_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1
    );
  }
}
```

You can check the issue here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ubizpu?file=src/app/CustomSearchPipe.pipe.ts

Any kind of help is appreciable.